# Why does $ \frac {a}{b}$ of $c$ mean $ \frac {a}{b} \cdot c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, arithmetic, fractions

When someone writes "$ \frac {a}{b}$ of $c$", why is the preposition "of" interpreted as multiplication of $c$ by $a/b$?

Comment: See this answer [Why does OF mean multiply ?](http://http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/58190.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be understood this way:

We divide $c$ into $b$ parts and take $a$ pieces. so $\frac{a}{b}\cdot c$ means $\frac{a}{b}$ of $c$, just like half (or say $\frac{1}{2}$) of one cake (or $1$).